# React, Redux, and Immutable

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

What are the advantages of using [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) with React (and optionally, Redux)? In Redux, I can simply use rest this in my reducers to return a new state:

```
const initialState = {
  activeTrackId: '',
  state: 'stopped',
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.PROCESS_TRACK_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        activeTrackId: action.state !== 'stopped' ? action.track._id : '',
        state: action.state,
      };
      // ...
```

The only scenario I've found it useful in was this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  const oldProps = Immutable.fromJS(this.props);
  const newProps = Immutable.fromJS(nextProps);

  return !Immutable.is(oldProps, newProps);
}
```

And that might even be misusing it, as far as I know.

Maybe someone could enlighten me as to the advantage of using Immutable in the context of React and Redux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7IdS-PbEgI) on the benefits and implementations for immutable data, from Lee's talk at React Conf 2015. As far as thinking about Immutable Data and React, I'd consider it essential viewing.

That aside, here are a few of my own thoughts on the matter.

## Terser Code

The more complex your state becomes, the harder it becomes to manage it with literals and the spread operator. Imagine that rather than being flat, you had a few levels of nested state:

```
const initialState = {
  core: {
    tracker: {
      activeTrackId: '',
      state: 'stopped'
    }
  }
};
```

Although it's still possible to use the spread operator, it starts to become tedious.

```
 return {
   ...state,
   core: {
     ...state.core,
     tracker: {
       ...state.core.tracker,
       activeTrackId: action.state !== 'stopped' ? action.track._id : '',
       state: action.state
     }
   }
 };
```

Now look at the equivalent with Immutable.js.

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const initialState = Map({
  core: Map({
    tracker: Map({
      activeTrackId: '',
      state: 'stopped'
    })
  })
});
```

Then we can use the persistent API to make deep changes to the structure.

```
return state
  .setIn(
    ['core', 'tracker', 'activeTrackId'],
    action.state !== 'stopped' ? action.track._id : ''
  )
  .setIn(
    ['core', 'tracker', 'state'],
    action.state
  );
```

It's worth mentioning that depending on the shape of your state, it might make more sense to split and nest your reducers instead.

## Structural Sharing

When you make a modification to an object with ImmutableJS it makes use of the fact that it's implemented with hash mapped vector tries to share most of the structure between the old object and the modified version.

When you use the spread operator to create new literals, you are forced to copy more data than you need to produce a new object.

## Safety

You can eliminate a huge class of bugs by guaranteeing that the object can't be mutated.

With mutable state, its possible to pass an object reference out to some other code, which could mutate it. Mutating an object isn't "an error", so you won't be told that it's changed and there'll be no stack trace either, meaning it can be very hard to work out where the mutation is coming from.

Wherever your immutable objects go, they'll be safe.

## Performance

You can use Immutable data structures to make more advanced decisions about whether to update components or not.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  const oldProps = Immutable.fromJS(this.props);
  const newProps = Immutable.fromJS(nextProps);

  return !Immutable.is(oldProps, newProps);
}
```

Although these sorts of deep comparisons might seem expensive, they prevent you from needing to diff or touch the DOM when the objects haven't changed.

This will be even more effective if your props themselves are immutable objects, as `fromJS` won't have to recreate the nested levels.

Comment: Great answer, Dan! This actually helps me understand Immutable more. I wasn't sure whether to use `Map`, or `Record`, or how to even use these things. I find the documentation a little confusing at times. I wonder why they chose to use a format like `.setIn(['core', 'tracker', 'activeTrackId'], value)` as opposed to `.setIn('core.tracker.activeTrackId', value)`.

Comment: If you'd prefer that style of notation, there are libraries like [dot-prop-immutable](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable).

Comment: PS: Even shorter, you can just use `Immutable.fromJS` and pass it anything, and it will set up the correct amount of maps and lists for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are careful, not to mutate the passed property, you don't have to use Immutable.js.

Since the `props` are reference any changes to it would affect the whole application.

Immutable.js guarantees that they can not be modified but it has a performance impact on large apps if you are not performing mutation, but the benefit is, it prevents any accidental pollution of the application state.

You could check out [these videos](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree) for a in depth explanation.